# Can an XSS attack an ASP.NET MVC without any persistence?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, nopcommerce

I am running into a very interesting XSS attack where it replaces image URLs on a nopCommerce 2.5 site's homepage with URLs to an overseas website. The resulting image is broken. It only works on the homepage and it doesn't seem to embed any code.  For kicks, I restarted the website and the normal images came back. Later in the day, the broken images reappeared. How is it possible to make a such a change without accessing the files directly? This doesn't seem to be a user session specific as I was able to see the problem from multiple machines and browsers.

Comment: Is your hosting environment under your control?

Comment: Yes it is. It's completely in my control and my wish is its command. It isn't listening to my command however.